# Find the interior, closure and boundary of the following set in these topologies:

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb N$ be the natural numbers, and the topologies over $\mathbb N$,
$$\tau_1=\{\varnothing,\mathbb N \}\cup\{A_n|n \in \mathbb N\}$$
$$\tau_2=\{\varnothing,\mathbb N \}\cup\{B_n|n \in \mathbb N\}$$
Where

$\{A_n|n \in \mathbb N\}=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$

$\{B_n|n \in \mathbb N\}=\{n,n+1,\dots \}$

Find for $A=\{3,4\}$ the Interior, closure, and the boundary for both topologies.

I tried and this is what I got, I think it's right for $\tau_1$ but I'm pretty sure I did something wrong for $\tau_2$.

For $\tau_1$:

$Int A=\{\varnothing\}$

$\overline A=\mathbb N-\{1,2\}=FrA$

For $\tau_2$:

$Int A=\{\varnothing\}=\overline A=FrA$

Did I got it right?

Comment: What's $FrA$? Do you mean the boundary? Note that $\overline{A}$ always contains $A$, so there's no way $\overline{A}$ is empty (in any topology). In $\tau_2$, $\overline{A}$ should be $\{1,2,3,4\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both case the conclusion $\mathsf{int}(A)=\{\varnothing\}$ is not correct, because $\{\varnothing\}$ is not a subset of $\{3,4\}$.

In both cases $\varnothing$ is the only open set that is a subset of $A=\{3,4\}$ so that $\mathsf{int}(A)=\varnothing$.

Concerning $\tau_1$ we indeed have $\overline A=\{3,4,5,6,\cdots\}$ (so here you are correct).

Concerning $\tau_2$ we have $\overline A=\{1,2,3,4\}$ (so here you are not correct).

The boundary is easily found by means of the general rule: $$\partial A=\overline A-\mathsf{int}(A)$$

Comment: $\{5,6,\dots\}\in\tau_2$ so its complement $\{1,2,3,4\}$ is closed. This with $\{3,4\}\subseteq\{1,2,3,4\}$. Further $\{1,2,3,4\}$ is evidently the smallest closed set that contains $A=\{3,4\}$. This makes us conclude that $\overline A=\{1,2,3,4\}$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer concerning $\tau_2$ is wrong. In this case, we have that $\overline A=\{1,2,3,4\}$, although it is correct that $\mathring A=\emptyset$.

Comment: The OP did not state that $\mathring{A}=\varnothing$ but that $\mathring{A}=\{\varnothing\}$.

Comment: Yes, I read your answer.